# Is ䷊ a chinese character?

Tags: characters, character-identification, character-variant

[Wiki refer of this character](https://zh.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E4%B7%8A)(here it's Chinese character)(you must see it in Chinese language)

[Wiki refer of chinese_characters](https://zh.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E6%B1%89%E5%AD%97)

These are Yijing Hexagram Symbols(4DC0— 4DFF).

In what degree can them be considered as Chinese characters? Or it's absolutely not.

䷀
䷁
䷂
䷃
䷄
䷅
䷆
䷇
䷈
䷉
䷊
䷋
䷌
䷍
䷎
䷏
䷐
䷑
䷒
䷓
䷔
䷕
䷖
䷗
䷘
䷙
䷚
䷛
䷜
䷝
䷞
䷟
䷠
䷡
䷢
䷣
䷤
䷥
䷦
䷧
䷨
䷩
䷪
䷫
䷬
䷭
䷮
䷯
䷰
䷱
䷲
䷳
䷴
䷵
䷶
䷷
䷸
䷹
䷺
䷻
䷼
䷽
䷾
䷿

Comment: If you define what a *Chinese character* is, and especially what a *Chinese character* **isn't**, then you'll have your answer.

Comment: @droooze, the problem is I don't know what it is exactly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Those are [六十四卦](https://zh.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E5%85%AD%E5%8D%81%E5%9B%9B%E5%8D%A6) symbols, which is extension of [八卦](https://zh.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E5%85%AB%E5%8D%A6)

They are not characters but symbols.

Each symbol has a corresponding Chinese character and representative meaning as the figures indicated

> For example, the symbol of the first 卦 is three solid lines. It is read as '乾' /quān/ and it represents '天'(heaven)

**八卦**

[image: 八卦]

**六十四卦**

[image: 六十四卦]

Comment: I am native chinese, but I'm not sure whether it's chinese character by the definition. I only care why it cannot be regard as chinese character.

Comment: @rambler Did you read my answer? They are not characters but symbols.

Each symbol has a corresponding Chinese characters and representative meaning.

Comment: @TangHo  You probably think character=文字. That's wrong. Characters include symbols and punctuation marks, while 文字 does not include symbols or punctuation marks.

Comment: @Victor The question is are they  **Chinese  Characters** . When I wrote character in my answer, I was referring to "Chinese characters" (中国字) not 'characters on keyboard' (字符)

Comment: anything you can type out on screen that take up one space (including space between words) is a character (字符), like this comment, I can still add 465 of them in it.

Comment: the above comment has 135 characters